# Как сделать todo lists на веб-странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, ruby

[image: todo lists]

Как сделать todo lists на веб-странице?
Я сделала на HTML и CSS фон и текст, но теперь не знаю как реализовать списки дел, как на картинке, которые можно создавать на сайте. Не подскажите, какие языки следует выучить для решения подобной задачи? Нужно ли для этого выучить Ruby?

Comment: Во-первых, чтобы сделать что-нибудь в браузере полюбому нужен javascript.

Во-вторых, сделать такую штуку с нуля красиво и функционально - это задача непростая. За пару дней не научишься. И за пару месяцев наверное тоже.

В-третьих, чтобы сделать это не только для личного пользования, нужно будет писать сервер. А это значит - какой-либо серверный язык и какой-либо движок баз данных. Языком может быть PHP там или C#. Может быть и Ruby. Конкретно Ruby учить не обязательно.

Comment: можно и на упомянутом вами javascript.

Comment: @konst54, можно можно. Вот только не думаю что новичков стоит еще нодой пугать)

Comment: Почитайте про frontend и backend, клиент-серверную архитектуру, если еще не читали.
Вы сделали интерфейс. Логику к нему можно реализовать и там же в javascript; но вы же хотите где-то хранить задачи? Значит, понадобится хранилище; можно хранить  локально на клиенте конечно, но тогда это все будет недоступно вам в сети. Так что стоит это делать на сервере, и использовать соответствующие технологии. Выбор языков огромен. Обычно ToDo-список рассматривается как учебная задача или задача для сравнения языков. Поэтому ставить вопрос как "какой язык выучить для нее" не совсем корректно.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите [todomvc.com](http://todomvc.com) там много примеров ToDo приложений на разных javascript-фреймфорков.